# Привязка к IsEnabled

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

XAML часть:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="myGroup" IsEnabled="{Binding Enable}"></TextBlock>
```

Описываю свойство, выше класс наследуется от интерфейса INotifyPropertyChanged 
(public partial class Index : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged):

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
public bool _enable;
public bool Enable
{
    get { return _enable; }
    set
    {
        _enable = value;
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Enable)));
    }
}
```

Создаю метод проверки, есть ли запись в БД, исходя из результата проверки должно изменяться значение IsEnabled:

```
public void CheckEnable(bool result)
{
    string connectionString = "SERVER = localhost; DATABASE = vbnzt; UID = vbnz; PASSWORD = ;";
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

    MySqlCommand check_group = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM groups WHERE liderId = " + Properties.Settings.Default.id.ToString(), connection);

    connection.Open();

    MySqlDataReader cg_result = check_group.ExecuteReader();

    if (cg_result.HasRows)
    {
        result = true;
    }
    else
    {
        result = false;
    }
    _enable = result;

    connection.Close();
}
```

Вызываю проверку перед загрузкой контента (в методе MainWindow_Loaded, который привязан к this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded; в конструкторе):

```
CheckEnable(_enable);
```

В другом классе (кликая по кнопке), вызываю проверку, передавая туда значение true:

```
Index index = new Index();
index.CheckEnable(true);
```

Нужно чтобы при клике по этой кнопке без перезагрузки приложения изменялось значение IsEnabled у ТекстБлока.

Comment: Если вы меняете значение привязанного свойства из кода и вам нужно, чтобы на это реагировал UI то в сеттере этого свойства вам необходимо вызывать событие `PropertyChanged`.

Comment: Уже пробовал и через INotifyPropertyChanged, ничего не выходит. Мне кажется я усложняю, это должно делаться проще. Попробую объяснить словами, может быть подскажете что-то.

Comment: Есть класс Index, в нем по большому счету 3 кнопки, которые вызывают 3 разных фрейма, мне нужно сделать так, что-бы до тех пор, пока проверка из одного из фреймов не пройдет (проверка описана выше в коде), одна из этих трех кнопок (которые описаны не во фрейме, а в классе Index) была IsEnabled=false. Сейчас проверка работает, но изменения IsEnabled применяются только после перезапуска приложения.

Comment: Другими словами, один фрейм отвечает за добавление записи в БД, а другой за его вывод. И до тех пор пока я не добавлю запись в БД, фрейм отвечающий за вывод должен быть недоступен, точнее кнопка для его вызова

Comment: `PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(CreateGroup.createGroup))); ` так делать нельзя, вы должные ссылаться на свойство принадлежащее этому же классу, а не другому. Сами подумайте: первый аргумент `this` сообщает в каком классе произошло изменение, а второй аргумент дает имя свойства из этого же класса.

Comment: Как вам правильно подсказывают, без `INotifyPropertyChanged` работать не будет. Так что покажите, что именно вы писали с `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Например, реализует ли ваш VM-класс интерфейс? Покажите его объявление.

Comment: Ну я как понимаю PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(CreateGroup.createGroup))); и есть реализация интерфейса INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: @Дмитрий: Не совсем. А как выглядит объявление вашего класса? Покажите.

Comment: public partial class Index : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Немного изменил логику и сделал более подробное описание, посмотрите, пожалуйста, может быть сейчас решение уже не так далеко

Comment: @Дмитрий: Ах, это Window! Окей, уже теплее. А как вы устанавливаете DataContext? Вангую, что никак.

Comment: Основное окно Window, в него вот таким способом подключаются Page:

Answer (score 0):

Вообще если уже начали с биндами работать- делайте по паттерну mvvm, по началу будет сложным, кода станет больше, но со своего личного опыта скажу, что данными намного легче управлять станет. И да, в свойстве вы поднимаете событие propertychanged? В xaml

```
 <TextBlock x:Name="myGroup" IsEnabled="{Binding Enable, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">.
```

UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged - слушает событие

```
        public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string property = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
```

Этот метод надо вызывать на Set свойства.